# Upload windows 10 Xbox DVR to Youtube

Tags: xbox-one, windows-10

Is there a possible way to upload games recorded with the Xbox-one DVR on Windows 10 to Youtube?

I have tried to upload the mp4-files that the Xbox-one DVR saves to a special folder, but this results in poor quality on Youtube. As I would like to upload the files without a drop in quality I would like to know if there is another possible way to do this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answer, you should be able to use the Windows 10 Xbox App to download the clip and then upload it to YouTube via normal means.

1. Navigate to the game DVR section in the application.
2. Switch the option at the top from "On this PC" to "On Xbox Live."  This will then show you all your clips from your Xbox One.
3. Select your game clip and click Download. You may or may not see a percentage of how long the download will take. I think if you have really fast Internet, it downloads very rapidly.
4. By default, the game clips should download to `C:\Users\YourName\Videos\Captures`.
5. Use this downloaded file to upload to YouTube.

As the other answer stated, it's not synced perfectly.  You may have to wait some time before you see your new clips appear in the Windows Xbox App.  Also note that you will need to be signed in to the Xbox App with the same Microsoft account you use for Xbox Live.

Comment: Whenever I this method the quality of the capture drops when it is uploaded to youtube. Could this have something to do with my settings when i upload to youtube or is there something else?

Comment: I would say its a YouTube setting or something.  My captures are relatively high quality in the Xbox App.

Answer (score 2):

Entering your gamertag into [xboxdvr.com](http://xboxdvr.com/) should give you access to your recordings. Each clip or screenshot will have a download link, as well as share functions, including a direct **upload to YouTube** button, Dropbox, etc.

Keep in mind that this site most likely aggregates from the official xbox API, so your most recent recordings will probably take a little time to show up, and will not be perfectly in sync with your console or xbox live's database.

Comment: @Artosvanstel if the answer worked for you, feel free to click checkmark to give us both some rep :)